# How to execute a fucntion based on the result of another function in Python

Tags: python, function

Im practicing around with Python and I wanted to execute my function to create a new password based on the result of the function that took the user's password and determined if its valid or invalid. If invalid, then execute two functions. One is the function for the user to choose what kind of password they want, second is the function to create the random password.

```
import re
import random
import string

# This function will check if the password is strong enough
# Paramter: none
# Return value: none
def password_strength_check():
    user_password = input("Enter your password: ")
    i = True
    while i:
        if (len(user_password)<6 or len(user_password)>12):
            break
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",user_password):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",user_password):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",user_password):
            break
        elif not re.search("[$#@]",user_password):
            break
        elif re.search("\s",user_password):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            i =False
            break

    if i :
        print("Not a Valid Password")
# Function: This function will create a random password using ascii tool. It will contain letters, digits and punctuation 
# Paramter: the length is the only paramter in order to give the oprion to the user what kind of password they want 
# return: None 
def newpassword(length):
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
    print("Random password is:", password)
def options():
    print("Please choose what kind of password you want")
    print(""
          "A: 8 character password"
          "B: 12 character password"
          "C: 16 character password ")

    user_choice = ""
    while user_choice.lower() != "a" or user_choice.lower() != "b" or user_choice.lower() !="b":
        user_choice = input("> ")
        if user_choice.lower() == "a":
            newpassword(8)
            break
        elif user_choice.lower() == "b":
            newpassword(12)
            break
        elif user_choice.lower() == "c":
            newpassword(16)
            break
        else:
            print("invalid choice")
```

Comment: What's the point of using `while` in the first function?

Comment: You have functions defined, you call them, you have if-elif-else chains: what is your actual problem?

Comment: **NOTE** python's random module is [not crypto-strength](https://pynative.com/cryptographically-secure-random-data-in-python/#:~:text=Random%20numbers%20and%20data%20generated,random%20elements%20from%20a%20sequence.). *Please* don't roll-your-own password generation (or [strength checks](https://xkcd.com/936/)) if you don't know what you're doing (you can find what you need easily enough via google search, *if* you know what to search for). If this is a homework assignment shame on your teacher.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for the feedback. Im just a student that is majoring in Intelligence and Cybersecurity and I decided this summer to learn python. After learning some of the basics, I decided to create a small project that is related to my field and I love passwords since I work closely with how they work and how they are cracked. I will deferentially look at the article.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz the first while function is a checklist to make sure in order for the password to be valid, it has to meet all criteria. However Im not sure if its suppose to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: I would start by googling "how to do x in python" for values of x like "securely generate random passwords" and "securely store passwords", etc. I would also google for articles about password strength. Honestly, it isn't really much more difficult (at least in Python) to do it the right way than what you have, it's mostly calling crypto-strength APIs instead of e.g. `random`. Happy coding!